# Error in connect() function in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

While using elastic package in R, I'm getting an message while using `connect("172.28.6.5")`.

Message details :

> Found http or https on es_host, stripping off, see the docs .

After this when I am running the command :

res <- Search(index = 'abc_20*', fields = c("Seq_Num"),scroll="5m",search_type = "scan")

It gives me error message :
Error: 404 - IndexMissingException[[abc_20%2A] missing]
This error is only shown in my laptop.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: is `ping 172.28.6.5` gives you any response?

Comment: To figure out if it's an error or a message as @jonathan-carroll suggests in his answer, please provide a screenshot (messages are also red).

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid that's entirely dependent on how you're using R (RStudio vs RGUI vs R in a terminal). But yes, some clarification of what's going wrong is in order.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll you're right, but the question is tagged with rstudio :)

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid my RStudio config doesn't highlight errors/warnings/messages in red; it's a theme choice. All beside the point.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll ah ok I didn't know that, I have the default settings. Thanks for the info! I'll take it back ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is that **exactly** what you did? I get no issues running that command.

```
library(elastic)
connect("172.28.6.5")
#> transport:  http 
#> host:       172.28.6.5 
#> port:       9200 
#> path:       NULL 
#> username:   NULL 
#> password:   <secret> 
#>   errors:     simple 
#> headers (names):  NULL
```

Looking at the [source for `elastic::connect()`](https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/blob/master/R/connect.R), assuming you've tried updating the package (this block traces back to April 2016)

```
  # strip off transport if found
  if (grepl("^http[s]?://", es_host)) {
    message("Found http or https on es_host, stripping off, see the docs")
    es_host <- sub("^http[s]?://", "", es_host)
  }
```

(note: this is a `message` not an `Error` as you have in your question) suggests you're passing in something that regex matches to `^http[s]?://`

Comment: i have done exactly that but it shows me message "Found http or https on es_host, stripping off, see the docs". After this i ran this command :        res <- Search(index = 'abc_20*', fields = c("Seq_Num"),scroll="5m",search_type = "scan") . It gives me error saying Error: 404 - IndexMissingException[[abc_20%2A] missing]  while the same command run perfectly fine in my friends laptop.

Comment: Could you maybe start a new session, run the original command (no point running things after it fails) and take a screenshot of the window? Very hard to debug based on 'I did that'.